# Как вызвать функцию из другого файла?

Tags: javascript, pug

```
mixin checkbox-buttons(params)
  .expandable-checkbox-list(id=params.inpId, type='button', onclick='testfunc()' )
    .expandable-checkbox-list__caption
      h3.expandable-checkbox-list__text= params.caption
      .expandable-checkbox-list__expand-more.material-icons expand_more
```

функция находится в файле test.js

```
function testfunc(){
  alert('hello');
}
```

по клику на элемент ничего не происходит

все js файлы подключаются в главный index.js так

```
function requireAll(requireContext) {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}

requireAll(require.context('./components', true, /^\.\/(?!.*(?:__tests__)).*\.(jsx?)$/));
```

сам index.js находится в самом низу body

если добавить вызов после функции

```
function testfunc(){
  alert('hello');
}
testfunc();
```

то она работает

Comment: Приложите лучше весь код, а если он слишком большой, то хотя бы фрагмент с подключение этого файла.

Comment: весь код чего? миксина? страницы на которой он вызывается? layout в который инклюдится страница? В layout'е блок скриптов в самом низу. В других js файлах код работает, хотя таких вызовов функции там нет

Comment: export функции из test.js => import туда где намерен использовать + при подключении скрипта в html указать type="module" в атрибутах скрипта